# History of relevant inventions in a specific CPC class

Tags: history, cited, evolution, overview

I want to do a patent search in a specific CPC class. How do I go about finding the most relevant patent documents from that class to quickly get an overview of the **history of inventions** in a specific field, without having to read at least 500 patent documents. Up until now I was sorting them by how often they got cited and even build myself a custom program (that costs me 1,00 € per search) for that, but I would like to find another way that is maybe even better.

Comment: There are many free patent search sites - why does a search cost ?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite You cannot search on those free patent search sites and order by number of times a patent document has been cited. I use Google BigQuery now for doing that and you have to pay there.

Comment: You can, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should explore the things free tools can do for you. I went in to Lens (formally "The Lens" [www.lens.org](http://www.lens.org)) and put in the search string "multiprocessor  cache  coherency".

The graphic displays included number of publications/patents over time, top assignees, top inventors and a bubble chart showing most cited.

[image]

Also, each hit shows the number of citations.

The data can be exported and one field you can chose to export is "cited by patent count". I searched on all patents in G06F12/082 and got 800+ hits. A screenshot of exported and sorted data is -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The EPO has a website for online search:

https://worldwide.espacenet.com/

Also, I recommend you Open Patent Services (OPS) if you good at programming. More info at:
https://www.epo.org/searching-for-patents/data/web-services/ops.html

It cost you if you use more than 4GB in a week.